# JSF - Role based pages display

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-security

I am starting a web app project using JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces. One of the requirements would be to display different page content based on the user role. E.g. only admins should see the menu item - User administration.

Security-wise I will go for Spring security.

How could this be achieved in an elegant way? Should I make a xhtml template for everyone and then create different pages for each role with the role-specific UI items?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use the attribute `rendered` + role check in components, for example for a submenu:

```
<p:submenu label="#{msg['header.management']}" rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('INTERNO')}">
        <p:submenu label="#{msg['header.roles']}" icon="ui-icon-contact">
                <p:menuitem value="#{msg['header.newRole']}" url="/pages/addRole.jsf" />
            <p:menuitem value="#{msg['header.mngRoles']}" url="/pages/viewRole.jsf" />
</p:submenu>
```

Being 'INTERNO' the role defined in Spring. I think this is pretty elegant.

To disable navigation for that pafe (or set of pages) you would still have to add an intercept to your `spring-security.xml` for example:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/pages/*Role*" access="hasRole('INTERNO')" />
```

Comment: While right, this does not prevent the user from directly entering the URL. ALWAYS use the web.xml to describe which pages are accessible to which roles. And add security to your bussiness layer, too. Security by obscurity does not work.

Comment: I don't think it is in the scope of this question, but I have added aditional info on how to address the case where the user directly accessing the URL.